# Calling session from one application to another

Tags: java, session, tomcat

I have a situation wherein I need to get a session variable that is created in one application to another application. Both are running on the same server (Tomcat). Is that possible? I have seen SSO but couldn't find any use. Is there any other way to do this?

Please let me know....

Thanks in advance....

Comment: I am thinking Web services would help in doing that but there is an easier way.

Comment: sorry for the delayed response.. It worked well I wrote a jsp page that will call the session an gives the id as response.. Though it is un preferable I had to do it..

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: session of one web application is not available to another one. Attempts to make it work are **usually** not worth the trouble and a sign of erroneous design.

If you want to share data between sessions/applications you would need to store it in a separate storage medium.

Comment: You may consider that if you have two tomcats, you also probably have two different servers, so file communication or different storage may not be possible or straight forward either...

Comment: Thanks guys, the clustering concept seems to be fine... But was thinking this way.. We have a servlet that saves all the data like the login ID and the other application that needs those values will call the servlet and get those values in response..

Answer (score 1):

Is possible, but not straight-forward, check out: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/cluster-howto.html